Adding TPM 2.0 module to Asrock Rack E3C256D2I motherboard to run Windows 11
I have the following board https://www.asrockrack.com/general/productdetail.asp?Model=E3C256D2I#Specifications
I am running Windows 10 with & Intel CPU and really happy with the setup. But with MSFT ending the support I need to migrate to Win 11. The board does not have TPM so I can't install.
Would adding this TPM 2.0 module (made for the board) allow me to upgrade to Windows 11

ASROCKRACK Accessory TPM 2.0 Module TPM Module Infineon SLB9665 13 Pin
Model TPM2-SLI
https://www.amazon.com/ASROCKRACK-Accessory-Infineon-SLB9665-TPM2-SLI/dp/B08MZ6BYGK

It does not list Win 10 as a compatibility on the Amazon web, but I think it is just a copy of specs when it was released.

"Would adding this TPM 2.0 module (made for the board) allow me to upgrade to Windows 11" - You can install Windows 11 without TPM support. It does not list Windows in the compatibility list due to the fact, the TPM is operating system agnostic. It also lists Windows 8.1 which means it's an older listing.

What I want to know is if adding this TPM module will allow to get Windows 11 via the regular Windows Update method - right now the home server is listed as "not eligible for Windows 11 due to missing TPM"

It should provided there is an option within the firmware currently that is disabled, due to the fact, you don't have a processor that supports fTPM nor dTPM.  Some motherboards firmware despite having a processor that supports fTPM does not allow you to enable TPM support even with a dTPM. I can't say if your motherboard is that way. You will have to determine that.
